# Which RAM configuration for a desktop upgrade?

Tags: memory, latency, triple-channel

I am trying to increase the RAM of my home computer, but I am unsure as to how much each aspect of RAM should be weighted (as to which is more important).

My motherboard has 6 slots, so I believe it is triple channeled.  It can run 1333 or 1600 speed RAM.  I also run this on Windows Home Premium, so I have a limit of 16GB of RAM.  Would it be better to get:

4 Sticks of 4 GB RAM, so I have a triple channel of 4, and a lone 4 stick, for a total of 16GB

or 3 Sticks of 4GB RAM, and 3 sticks of 1GB RAM (the 1 GB sticks I have currently), so that I have triple channel for both sets, however I only have 15GB?

Assuming everything is the same (latency, frequency, etc), which would give a better performance?  Is the triple channeling worth not having that extra gigabyte?

The more general question I suppose would be, how do you really weight the different aspects of RAM (capacity vs speed vs latency vs # of sticks vs channeling, etc)?

Comment: What is your motherboard model?

Comment: My PC is an Alienware Aurora PC.  The motherboard is an Alienware 04VWF2 Motherboard, though I haven't been able to find a separate documentation sheet for it yet, besides tee PC's general instruction manual.

Comment: More RAM is always better. The speed difference is negligible, especially if you're running a standard hard drive and CPU. I always go for as much RAM as I can afford.

Comment: Okay, will a motherboard more than likely accept such a configuration as 4 4GB sticks, even though it will be 1 triple channel set, and 1 lone stick?